# PostGIS Out of DB raster Configuration fails to register a raster

Tags: postgis, gdal, raster2pgsql

I have been trying to get my postgis enabled postgres database to register raster data in out of db and it is not working. All I get is a distorted image shown below:

[image]

If i use raster2pgsql to keep the raster data in the database everything works. I'm on windows 7, have qgis 2.8.4 installed and OSGEO4W, postgis 2.1 and postgres 9.3.5. According to the install notes I have to set some environment variables in windows to enable the out-of-db option and I've done that (POSTGIS_ENABLE_OUTDB_RASTERS and POSTGIS_GDAL_ENABLED_DRIVERS). Everything inside the database columns seems to be in order.

Anyone has any suggestions on what to try next?

---

Installed all the required software on a new machine. The problem still persists. Next I will try to go to the latest version of postGIS and test if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on the folder you have the data in.  The Postgres service account needs to be able to access them and access them by the same path you loaded them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've given 'Everyone' full read and write access to the folder containing the raster. The same issue still exists.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly was the format of your `raster2pgsql` command?

I assume you know that for out-of-db rasters you need to provide the **full** path to the file(s).